# Can't connect to X11 window server using ': 2.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, linux, swing, vnc

I have connected Linux server (centos 64bit)using VNC viewer. Then I have tried to run java swing application using this command (java -jar app.jar).

I am getting this error "Can't connect to X11 window server using ': 2.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable"

Comment: could you run other x application like xclock/xcalc?  What this says is display server at 2.0 is not allowing client to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. ensure there is display at :2.0  (looks like you had **white space**?)
2. ensure that the display allows clients to connect from some where. (`xhost + ...`)

( xhost + will allow every client to connect. You can restrict to your ip or some thing like that.)

Comment: tnx for your response. I am new in linux. could you please tell me the step to check display and xhost

Comment: using root user. I am able to open the swing ui. but not from other user. any idea how to set the same ui settings for other user also?